# python's beautiful soup module giving error

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using the following code  in an attempt to do webscraping .

```
import sys , os
import requests, webbrowser,bs4
from PIL import Image
import pyautogui

p = requests.get('http://www.goal.com/en-ie/news/ozil-agent-eviscerates-jealous-keown-over-stupid-comments/1javhtwzz72q113dnonn24mnr1')

n = open("exml.txt" , 'wb')
for i in p.iter_content(1000) :
    n.write(i)

n.close()
n = open("exml.txt" , 'r')

soupy= bs4.BeautifulSoup(n,"html.parser")


elems = soupy.select('img[src]')

for u in elems :
    print (u)
```

so what I am  intending to do is to extract all the image links that is there in the xml response obtained from the page .
(Please correct me If I am wrong in thinking that requests.get returns the whole static html file of the webpage that opens on entering the URL)

However in the line :

```
 soupy= bs4.BeautifulSoup(n,"html.parser")
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../perl/webscratcher.txt", line 24, in <module>
    soupy= bs4.BeautifulSoup(n,"html.parser")
  File "C:\Users\Kanishc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 191, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
  File "C:\Users\Kanishc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 24662: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am clueless about the error and the "Appdata" folder is empty .

How to proceed further ?

Post Trying suggestions :

I changed the extension of the filename to py and this error got removed . However on the following line :

soupy= bs4.BeautifulSoup(n,"lxml") I am getting the following error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\perl\webscratcher.py", line 23, in 
soupy= bs4.BeautifulSoup(p,"lxml")
File "C:\Users\PREMRAJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4_*init*_.py", line 192, in **init**
elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

How to tackle this ?

Comment: Why is your Python code in a folder named `perl`, in a file with the extension `.txt`?

Comment: You are writing the file as binary, maybe that's messing up the text: `open("exml.txt" , 'wb')`. Try `'w'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-complicating things. Pass the bytes content of a Response object directly into the constructor of the BeautifulSoup object, instead of writing it to a file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get('http://www.goal.com/en-ie/news/ozil-agent-eviscerates-jealous-keown-over-stupid-comments/1javhtwzz72q113dnonn24mnr1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
for element in soup.select('img[src]'):
    print(element)
```

Comment: Sorry , this did not work. It said " Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?"

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention. Yes, `lxml` is a different parser, more efficient than `html.parser` You should be able to get it with `pip install lxml`. If you're on Linux, you might wanna do `sudo pip3 install lxml`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do your Python scripts have extension `.py`? It doesn't seem like it, judging by the error you posted. @KanishkViman

Comment: No they have .txt . Seems like there is something interesting here in the difference of extensions .

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you you might want to do a review on working with BeautifulSoup. I referenced an old project of mine and this is all you need for printing them. Check the [BS documents](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to find the exact syntax you want with the select method.

This will print all the img tags from the html

```
import requests, bs4


site = 'http://www.goal.com/en-ie/news/ozil-agent-eviscerates-jealous-keown-over-stupid-comments/1javhtwzz72q113dnonn24mnr1'

p = requests.get(site).text

soupy = bs4.BeautifulSoup(p,"html.parser")


elems = soupy.select('img[src]')

for u in elems :
    print (u)
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xff' in file nm.txt on line 1, but no encoding declared

Comment: Sorry , but would need a little more explanation here

Comment: I am running it using command prompt and providing the file as an argument to the python interpreter  and the file name that i am providing is .txt . Did you mean this ?

Comment: save your python file as "yourprogram.py" it looks like you have it saved as a .txt. The ending of the file name determine how your computer reads a file. If you save it as .txt it will think it is just a text file. If you save it as a .py it will know that is a python program and will run the code

Comment: But some part of the code is running . So did you mean that some particular functions don't run well when the file is not saved as .py ?

Comment: @Digbigig : How to save it as .py . Anyhow even if I rename it to something.py , it will wok only when I provide the file name as "something.py.txt"

Comment: Five days later youre still trying to argue that you can save python files as .txt rather than just changing it to .py? 
`File "../../perl/webscratcher.txt", line 24, in <module>` webscratcher.txt will be read as if it were a file that contained one large string. change it to webscratcher.py

Comment: Hey sorry , it  did not give this error any more but for the line soupy = bs4.beautifulsoup(p . "lxml") I am geting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\perl\webscratcher.py", line 23, in <module>
    soupy= bs4.BeautifulSoup(p,"lxml")
  File "C:\Users\PREMRAJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 192, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: Put the code in hastebin or pastebin so I can see the whole thing

Comment: You really should take some time to actually learn what youre doing. All you had to do was code my code I answered with directly. https://hastebin.com/vaxawumeqo.swift

Comment: Thanks ..I missed the .txt part. I know the code was wrong but I want to understannd deeply as to why it was failing